# what does STDOUT->autoflush(1) do in Perl?

Tags: perl

I've found a variety of information regarding autoflushing in Perl, but can't find any mention of a line formatted exactly like this:

```
STDOUT->autoflush(1);
```

This is included in a program I'm analyzing, and I want to understand better what it does. There is also this at the beginning of the program:

```
use IO::Handle;
```

...which I think might be related, but it also doesn't mention this method in its documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method *is* listed in [IO::Handle](https://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Handle.html#METHODS) which you noticed

> ```
> ...
> $io->autoflush ( [BOOL] )                         $|
> ...
> ```

whereby `$|` is set/unset, and it sends you to [`$|` in perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$%7C) for explanation

> If set to nonzero, forces a flush right away and after every write or print on the currently selected output channel.

[As of v5.14](https://metacpan.org/pod/perl5140delta#Filehandle-method-calls-load-IO::File-on-demand) you don't have to `use IO::Handle` for this as [IO::File](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/File.html) is `require`d when needed.

This method is special in that it turns autoflush on even without value supplied,

```
$io->autoflush;  # turned on ($| gets set)
```

while other related ones don't change the current value when called without argument.

Comment: To clarify, my confusion is regarding how the method becomes available on STDOUT (apparently automatically just by using IO::Handle). The documented case you mention is just on an object $io which is different, it seems to me.

Comment: @Stephen  Follow the link "_As of v5.14_", it does explain it. I added a comment to highlight

Comment: OK thanks, I think I see how everything comes together now.

Comment: BTW, what is "block buffering"? It says that when writing to pipes STDOUT will be block buffered.

Comment: Nevermind got my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008273/what-do-chunk-block-offset-buffer-and-sector-mean

Comment: @Stephen In a rush here, in short: (1) `STDOUT` (and Co) are `IO::File` objects, see with the oneliner: `perl -wE'say *{$main::{STDOUT}}{IO}'`  (2) Perl output is buffered differently depending on where it goes; normally for terminal it's line buffered while for pipes (and files) it goes in whole blocks (I think normally 64kB these days)

Comment: @Stephen More generally, this works for any filehandle. So `open my $fh,...` and call `IO::File` methods on `$fh` and the module is loaded and it works. All filehandles are `IO::File` in newer Perls -- I think they get `bless`ed in `IO::File` when created but I couldn't find this in documentation. At any rate, the quoted docs specify that they are objects at least once the need arises.

Comment: @Stephen Methods from `IO::File` all work on _file-related_ filehandles. For others (say, sockets) look for methods in `IO::Handle`.  The `IO::File` inherits from `IO::Handle` and from `IO::Seekable` (file related ones). Most methods, by far, come from `IO::Handle` though.

Comment: Re "*my confusion is regarding how the method becomes available on STDOUT*", File handles are blessed into IO::Handle or IO::File depending on your version of Perl. (`perl -MScalar::Util=blessed -E'say blessed(*STDOUT{IO})'`)